# stream file that is currently being written to

Tags: go

Is it possible to, in a goroutine, stream a file as it is being written to by a subprocess command? The goal here is to capture the output as both a file *and* stream it live. I have:

```
cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, c.Bin, args...)
// CANT USE NON FILE!!
// https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23019
tempout, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "workerout")
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
tempoutName := tempout.Name()
defer os.Remove(tempoutName) // clean up

temperr, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "workererr")
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
temperrName := temperr.Name()
defer os.Remove(temperrName) // clean up

cmd.Stdout = tempout
cmd.Stderr = temperr

err = cmd.Start()

// Stream the logs
// Does not work. Flushing issue???
/*
    ro := bufio.NewReader(tempout)

    go func() {
        line, _, _ := ro.ReadLine()
        logger.Debug(line)
    }()

    re := bufio.NewReader(temperr)

    go func() {
        line, _, _ := re.ReadLine()
        logger.Error(line)
    }()
*/
cmd.Wait()
return tempout.Read(... // read the file into a string and return it
```

The commented out section of the code seems to show the logs only once the command exits (either by ctx being cancelled, or it finishes), in that it does not log in real time. Is there a way to make this log in real time?

Comment: @MuffinTop the issue is the github issue linked in the comment. If you have an idea how my code could be improved while still getting around that issue (I must have a file interface!) then I would love to accept that as an answer. To be clear, I need both the file to return, but also the realtime logs, and that issue forces me to have a file interface.

Comment: specifically, i must fight around this issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23019

Comment: its a terraform command that when piped to a MultiWriter does show logs in real time; it's only being "buffered" in the code I linked above which does not work. Im ging to try your playground next

Comment: i might need this: https://codeeval.dev/gist/7cca5f1526b2785e03febc16542b96ea